# How can I reduce the size of rustup install?

Tags: linux, docker, rust, rustup

I have [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/s1n7ax/dotnvim/blob/3398ff3cb36864e421c8de8a31850ed4d28f53cd/Dockerfile) which builds my Neovim setup inside an Arch Linux container. Following logs show the amount of space each layer takes. The command `rustup install nightly` took `1.05GB` of space which sounds unusual to me. Is there any way to reduce the amount of space taken my Rust nightly?

```
$ docker history s1n7ax/neovim:latest
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
de4cac3f0fe9   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /root                 0B
92121272827c   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c nvim     --headless     -c 'set c…   692MB
8779585b1604   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c nvim     --headless     -c 'autoc…   82.3MB
1b0cf08fadcf   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c sed -i "s/max_jobs *= *[0-9]\+,*/…   12.4kB
26ee8d4eb0e6   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c cp server/*.jar ~/.local/share/nv…   2.1MB
e0ea809b07bd   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c yarn build-plugin                    145MB
cd66bd36b04c   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c yarn                                 320MB
e6ed455333a2   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /vscode-java-test     0B
881aece35a57   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c cp     com.microsoft.java.debug.p…   2.86MB
01817765eefa   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c ./mvnw clean install                 160MB
0496aff9c7e9   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c chmod u+x mvnw                       0B
5675cbc79777   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /java-debug           0B
a27056432eb9   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/micr…   12.4MB
947e120c0d95   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/micr…   2.83MB
a30656b6fa58   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nvim/lsp_…   0B
21699318e786   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /                     0B
42ce1c7cdea4   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c git clone --recurse-submodules -j…   2.45MB
478422a36727   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/local/bin/nvim /usr/sb…   0B
6eb281356e67   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c make install                         34.6MB
7b685c7218a0   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release        329MB
ca9dbcc78168   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /neovim               0B
b3d8d34a8377   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c git clone https://github.com/neov…   253MB
e1d162cf132c   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=~/.yarn/bin:~/.c…   0B
a7ba8d0af37f   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=~/.cargo/bin:~/.…   0B
22a3b31751f9   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=~/.local/bin:/us…   0B
33649aec725c   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV SHELL=/bin/bash          0B
9e8b31edbbde   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c cargo install taplo-cli              106MB
7b45e6a9f648   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c cargo install stylua                 110MB
92e12231c110   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade autopep8       728kB
45ad80c3b346   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c yarn global add prettier             38.1MB
83072229ae66   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c rustup default nightly               103B
2d24ac105fec   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c rustup install nightly               1.05GB
c93fbc7c84ca   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c pacman -S --needed --noconfirm   …   1.12GB
38f82d2a27d2   7 hours ago   /bin/sh -c pacman -Syu --noconfirm              35MB
ec4c97123c01   4 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/usr/bin/bash"]        0B
<missing>      4 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B
<missing>      4 days ago    /bin/sh -c ldconfig &&     sed -i '/BUILD_ID…   32.3kB
<missing>      4 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f054defad7465e3fc…   396MB
```

Comment: Have you looked at which folders specifically take that much storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rustup install --profile=minimal nightly` reduce the space by almost half. I can see, minimal has no docs included.